# is it possible to overcome type erasure in akka receive?

Tags: scala, akka, type-erasure

I have a trait and implementing akka actor that can't properly differentiate the types of incoming messages due to type erasure, and so the first case is matching all messages.

I'm using scala 2.10.x, and from reading many other answers I know that it is possible to recover type information inside a trait using `TypeTag` or `ClassTag`, but I can't figure out how to apply it (if it is possible) within the akka receive.

My  (very simplified) example is as follows. Is it possible properly match the generic types?

```
package com.ebay.box.canada.batch.jobs.siteMap

import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSelection
import akka.actor.Actor.Receive
import scala.reflect.ClassTag


trait MessageProcessor[A,B] {
  this: Actor =>

  val destA: ActorSelection
  val destB: ActorSelection

  def processA(a: A): A
  def processB(a: B): B

  def receive: PartialFunction[Any,Unit] = {
    case a: A =>
      destA ! processA(a)
    case b: B =>
      destB ! processB(b)
  }
}

class StringIntProcessor(val destA: ActorSelection, val destB: ActorSelection) extends MessageProcessor[String,Int] with Actor {
  def processA(a: String) = { a + "1" }
  def processB(b: Int) = { b + 1 }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `def process(a: B): B` be `def process(b: B): B`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I've edited the example code. Technically, the difference is immaterial to the compiler or the problem at hand. Stylistically, though, that's not what I intended, and the naming should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get at `TypeTag[A]` or `ClassTag[A]` in your trait -- type tags/class tags are always part of the implicit argument list to a method call. You might be able to use an abstract class instead, with implicit constructor arguments:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

abstract class MessageProcessor[A,B]()(implicit cta: ClassTag[A], ctb: ClassTag[B]) {
   def receive = {
     case a: Any if a.getClass() == cta.runtimeClass =>
       process(a.asInstanceOf[A])
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

(Not tested!)

Supposing that you can change the code that sends the message, can I suggest the following design instead? MessageProcessor is now a typeclass, so that you can add any number of message types. By sending a closure as the message, you can smuggle any amount of context into the call site.

```
class MessageReceiver extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case fn: Function0[Unit] =>
      fn()
  }
}

trait MessageProcessor[A] {
  val dest: ActorSelection
   def process(a: A): A
}

object Processors {

  implicit object StringProcessor extends MessageProcessor[String] {
    val dest: ActorSelection = Wellknown.stringDest
    def process(a: String): String = a + "1"
  }

  implicit object IntProcessor extends MessageProcessor[Int] {
    val dest: ActorSelection = Wellknown.intDest
    def process(a: Int): Int = a + 1
  }

  def sendMessage[A](msg: A)(implicit ev:[MessageProcessor[A]]): Unit = {
    val block: Function0[Unit] = { () =>
      ev.dest ! ev.process(msg)
    }

    val msgDest = system.actorOf[Props[MessageReceiver]], "msgDest")
    msgDest ! block
  }
}
```

(Also not tested!)

Comment: Does the implicit ClassTag have to be on the constructo--can it not be an implicit val or an implicit on the receive PartialFunction?

Comment: Pretty sure it can't -- the type of `receive` is `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`, you can't change it to have an implicit argument list. Anyway, it's the types of A and B you need to capture, which has to happen when MessageProcessor is reified. (i.e. when the concrete types are supplied).

Comment: Ah, ok.. so I think I understand why `receive` can't be changed, since I can't change the method signature while implementing it (makes you wonder why the akka folks didn't add an implicit parameter themselves, since class matching is so important to actors), but isn't this the case where you use a val in the body of the code that is set by the concrete class's constructor? (similar to how I'm defining `destA` and `destB` in the examaple)

Comment: Actually, in your design the erased type is sufficient -- the type is either `String` or `Int`. Where TypeTags might help would be to distinguish between e.g. `Option[String]` and `Option[Int]`, where the erased type is just `Option[_]`. TypeTags came in later than Akka, though. The purpose of my `MessageProcessor` trait is to tie together a type, a destination and a processing method. You should check out typeclasses, which is the technique I've used here.

Comment: I had to edit the code a bit to get it to compile properly (the `process` method was actually a duplicate, again because of type erasure), but when I compile it, I get the warnings that the `type pattern is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say the erased type is sufficient? It appears that the compiler is unable to distinguish between A and B because they are both generic are erase (i guess) to `Any`. I will look into "typeclasses" you have used to see how they can be applied to my larger problem.

Comment: I meant that if you have an `Any` in your `receive` function, you can distinguish between a `java.lang.String` and a `scala.Int` by calling `.getClass()`. What's not working the way you expect is the type check in `case a: A =>`. The actual type of A is not known at compile time.